# Reduce white space between Spinner items

Tags: android, android-spinner

I wanted to reduce the white spaces between the items in my `Spinner`.
I looked things up on the Internet, but I can't seem to find it.
What did I try? Not much to be honest, I can't find anything really.
I tried to change the padding of my Spinner, but that (ofcourse) affects the Spinner itself, not the items within.

As you can see below, the white space between the items is pretty big. How to reduce this?

This is on Android 2.3.3

[image]

However, on Android 4.0+, the space is already a lot better:
[image]

Comment: You have to replace the set dropdown *resource* of the adapter to your own

Comment: @Mango Ah, you mean to make a own adapter in a xml file, and use that one. If so, I am on it now :)

Comment: You probably used an adapter already. All you'd need to do is make the XML for the overriden dropdown resource and use android id's, if applicable.

Comment: I do not recommend this at all. Those spinner styles are android device  specific. It matches every other spinner that the phone user will come across, and keeps with the whole device theme. If you change it, it will affect all devices to your new style. Which will look out of place on some/many devices. Unless you create an xml for each API.. All the effort for what? Because you want a smaller list.. Consider that the user is used to spaces between items, and having to scroll the dropdown list.

Comment: @Doomsknight True, but my "customer" wanted it smaller. I used this: `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` this is also from Android. This makes it smaller (I think it is too small) but I let him decide.

Comment: What you've done there is set the dropdown resource as the item resource. (the thing you see when its not active) `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` is the dropdown one. If hes happy with that then fair enough. But like you say, it makes it too small Imo too.  You could use some addon to force everthing to the holo theme. And look like android 4.0 in all cases. I think the sherlock helps with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can write s custom Spinner Adapter and override getView/getDropDownView to write your own view. hereis  some [sample code](https://github.com/ravivyas84/AndroidSpinnerHint)  which might help.

Comment: Not `getView()` but `getDropDownView()`, in this case